# Python:Continuing try loop until first item in list is found

Tags: python, exception, loops, try-catch

I would like to use a try statement or any other method to find the closest item after the given variable in a list: I have the following code. In this example I want the code to keep adding one day to d1 until the first datetime object in list pj is found and then return the index of that corresponding list element. So here d1 should equal datetime.datetime(1922,01,06) and d1_index = 1. The range function yields the last element in the list, so obviously I need to change that condition but not sure what the right way forward is,
Thanks heaps,

Kane

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import dateutil.relativedelta as rd


pj = [datetime.datetime(1921,12,31), datetime.datetime(1922,01,06), datetime.datetime(1922,01,07), datetime.datetime(1922,01,10), datetime.datetime(1922,01,12)]

d1 = datetime.datetime(1922,01,02)
d2 = datetime.datetime(1929,12,31)

for i in range(0,50):
    try: 
        d1_index = pj.index(d1)

    except ValueError:
        d1 = d1 +rd.relativedelta(days = +i)

        continue
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goodness no.

```
>>> bisect.bisect_left(pj, d1)
1
>>> pj[bisect.bisect_left(pj, d1)]
datetime.datetime(1922, 1, 6, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Hey @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams. What if I want the preceding index number / value ??